# Image has a weird icon and outline over it

Tags: html, css, image, hyperlink, photos

I need a big banner at the top of the screen going from end to end. It has to be a link and on the banner is an image. I have all that set up and working. However, around it all is a gray box and in the top left corner is the icon that is displayed when no image is found. How do I remove the box and the icon?

header.php

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>

<a class="vcuLink" href="http://www.vcu.edu/" >
    <div id="topBanner" class="vcuBanner">
        <img class="vcuLogo" src="vcu.png" width="910" height="59">
    </div>
</a>

<div id="page" class="site">
    <div class="site-inner">
```

I do not think showing more is necessary.

style.css

```
.vcuBanner {
    position: relative;
    background-color: black;
    z-index: 100;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 62px;
    top=0;
}

.vcuLogo {
    position: relative;
    background:url(vcu.png)no-repeat center;
    height: inherit;
    width: inherit;
    z-index: 101;
}
```

EDITS: More information and a screen shot.

When either the background:url line in style.css or the img tag in header.php is deleted, the image in the banner stops showing. However, when the img tag is there so is the weird icon and outline, leading me to believe that the img tag is the culprit.

Screenshot:
[image]

In the VCU banner at the very top, you can see what I am talking about. In Internet Explorer, the icon at the top left is an X button instead and there is no outline.

Comment: Why do you have the PNG file as both the image and the background image of the image? What's the point of that? You're also missing a space after the closing parenthesis in the background declaration, and the ‘top’ declaration for the banner is HTML, not CSS. That may be part of the issue.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I have the image in both places because for whatever reason, when I remove the PNG file from either location it stops displaying. What do you mean about missing a space in the background declaration? Thanks to the catch with 'top', I removed it.

Comment: There should be a space between the closing parenthesis of the url and the word “no-repeat”. I would guess that makes the url invalid and the browser ignore the entire line (or misinterpret the path and fail to load the image). Have you tried using the browser inspector to see what's actually being displayed? Also, please include a screenshot (or a link) so we can see exactly how it looks.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I have added edits with the screenshot and some extra information. Adding the space after the background url didn't change anything on Chrome. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many possible causes for this, so I’ll try an educated guess at what seems the most likely cause.

I don’t know where your files are located relative to one another, but the way your markup and CSS here is written, the file `vcu.png` should be in **the same folder** as the PHP file where you’re displaying it (presumably `index.php`, given the URL in your address bar) for the `<img>` tag to work. Similarly, it must be in the same folder as the CSS file for the background declaration to work.

Since the position of the `<img>` tag itself is not specified in your CSS, it should show up in the top left corner of the container. The background image is centred, so it should show up in the centre. Given that there is an image in the centre and a missing image icon on the left, it would seem it is the HTML `<img>` tag that points to a nonexistent file. That in turn means that the PNG file is in the same folder as the CSS file, but in a different folder than the PHP file. Perhaps the CSS and PNG files are in a subfolder called `style` or something like that?

> When either the background:url line in style.css or the img tag in header.php is deleted, the image in the banner stops showing.

This makes sense. Since the CSS-defined background is declared on the **image** tag (not the containing `<a>` or `<div>`), removing the tag from the HTML markup naturally also removes the background image. Conversely, since the HTML tag is pointing to an incorrect path, having the tag there also means there will be a missing image icon.

You can solve this in two simple ways:

1. Figure out where the image is located relative to your `index.php` file, and make sure you point to the correct location (perhaps `src="style/vcu.png"` or something like that). Then style the `<img>` tag with something like `margin: 2px auto;` to centre the image and give it a couple of pixels of space at the top and bottom, and get rid of the background declaration in your CSS.
2. Remove the `<img>` tag from your HTML altogether, replace it with `&nbsp;` (to make the containing `<a>` non-empty), and style the container to be `display: block`.

The first yields more semantic code and would be my preference; but both should render the same in regular browsers. Removing the `<img>` tag also removes its `alt` attribute, however, so users relying on text-to-speech systems will have no way of knowing what that link actually does, since the only meaningful content it will contain is a non-breaking space.